# How to register values to ttk.Spinbox via keyboard entry?

Tags: python, tkinter

Can a `ttk.Spinbox` widget allow a user to type in values to it's entry field and have it registered? If so, how can I do so?

I am aware that it is possible to use the `.set()` method on the ttk.Spinbox's `textvariable` to alter its value. But this isn't what I was thinking off. Instead, I would simply like to allow the user to click on the `ttk.Entry` widget of the `ttk.Spinbox` and manually type in values there and have it registered to its `textvariable`. Presently, I can type in values there but nothing happens when I press the `Return` key.

Thank you.

Comment: What makes you think that this doesn't work? What do you expect to happen when you press the `Return` key?

Comment: @fhdrsdg I see what you mean.....I have to bind keyboard entry to the widget.... I will have a go at this.... brain freeze ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a ttk.Spinbox widget allow a user to type in values to it's entry field and have it registered? If so, how can I do so?

If you associate a variable with the `textvariable` attribute, there's nothing else you need to do. Anytime the user changes the value, whether by the arrows or by typing into the editable portion of the widget, the value in the variable will instantly be updated.

You can verify this yourself by creating a spinbox and a label, both associated with the same variable. You can then see the label being updated in real time when you edit the spinbox.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
spinvar = tk.IntVar()
spinbox = ttk.Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=100, textvariable=spinvar)
label = ttk.Label(root, textvariable=spinvar)
spinbox.pack()
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

> Presently, I can type in values there but nothing happens when I press the Return key.

If you want something to happen when the user presses the `<Return>` key, you have to add a binding to call a function.

Example:

```
def do_something(event):
    print("do something:", spinvar.get())
spinbox.bind("<Return>", do_something)
```

Comment: Thanks. I had jus solved it when your answer arrived. ;)